# How to get the Header id and Div id of an Accordion jQuery?

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have a simple accordion, where each header has its own id, and div has its own id.

How do I create an object that gets the current selected header id, or div id?

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <h6 id="myAttributes">Attributes</h6>
    <div id="divAttributes">
    </div>

    <h6 id="myConstants">Constants</h6>
    <div id="divConstants">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am stuck at:

```
jQuery(function () {
    $("#mainDiv").accordion({
        activate: function () {

        }
    });
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On activate get the element with the class `.ui-accordion-header-active`, which is automatically added by accordion.

```
jQuery(function () {
    $("#mainDiv").accordion({
        activate: function () {
                  alert($('.ui-accordion-header-active').attr('id'));
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3jHwC/1/

Using the same selector you can actually get the active header from outside the accordion's triggered events: `$('#mainDiv .ui-accordion-header-active')`

Answer (score 4):

`activate` option function gets two arguments `event` and `ui`: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate

You can then get all the data from `ui`:

```
activate: function (event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.newPanel[0].id);
}
```